# Replace ImageView from PNG to GIF

Tags: android, replace, imageview, png, gif

I want to replace ImageView from PNG to GIF. I tried with this code:

```
        ImageView kotek = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        nYAn.setImageResource(R.drawable.kot);
```

But GIF isn't animate.
What i should do?
Sorry for my bad English :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ImageView` does not support animated GIFs. Either [convert the animated GIF into an `AnimationDrawable`](http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/10/01/converting-animated-gifs-animationdrawables.html), or [use a third-party library](https://android-arsenal.com/search?q=gif) for displaying the animated GIFs.

Comment: So how i can replace ImageView to GIF? I can also replace it with a GIF frames , but how ?